# How to import airbnbapi?

Tags: node.js, import

Following this tutorial: https://github.com/zxol/airbnbapi

and would like to import SDK

```
var airbnb = require('airbnbapijs')
```

I do not see any component like `airbnbapijs`. Shouldn't it exist to be import into my web app?

Comment: In order to use it, you have to install it first with `npm install airbnbapijs` in the project root (or at the level where `package.json` exists). Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @Janos Yeah, i cannot see any component being exported

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, I could install it, but the next step I am curious about

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the issue here. Once you installed it and `require`d, then you should be able to work with it, for example: `airbnb.getGuestInfo(2348485493)`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek there is no exported module i can see when i looked at source code. And that is the reason it could not find it

Comment: Are we looking at the same module? ;) In `package.json` the `main` points to `build/main.js` file. And when I look at this file I can see the `module.exports = abba;` line. The same line exists at the very end of `src/main.js` file

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek yes same module, not sure why i cannot see methods

Comment: I have just tried it here: https://repl.it/repls/DualStrictDisassembler and it seems to work

Comment: In TS i am facing issue, javascript does work

Comment: Ahh TS! I think it's worth pointing that out in the question then. I thought we are talking about clean Node.js